# Could Kyle Katarn return to Star Wars canon?

Tags: star-wars

Even *if* there were some changes to his story (as he was involved in the theft of the original Death Star plans), could [Kyle Katarn](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kyle_Katarn) return?

Comment: This seems impossible to answer without being an employee of Disney

Answer (score 2):

Impossible to say, other than "anything is *possible*". It is even impossible to give a probability, other than to say that other Legends ships, planets, and famous characters have become Disney canon, most notably **Grand Admiral Thrawn**:

[image: Admiral Thrawn, blue humanoid alien with red irises, short dark blue hair, and two lizards on his shoulders]

See [Enter Thrawn: A Q&A with Timothy Zahn](https://www.starwars.com/news/qa-with-timothy-zahn).

A couple of stories related to Thrawn coming back and canon:

- ["Grand Admiral Thrawn Returns to the STAR WARS Canon", Jess Jane for *Nerdist*, February 4, 2016](https://web.archive.org/web/20180616080158/https://nerdist.com/grand-admiral-thrawn-star-wars-canon-expanded-universe-star-wars-rebels/)
- ["Every New (and Returning!) Development *Thrawn* Brings to the *Star Wars* Universe", Katharine Trendacosta for *Gizmodo*, April 12, 2017](https://io9.gizmodo.com/every-new-and-returning-development-thrawn-brings-to-1794265990)